# How would I modify the position of a card in a table with only a single query?

Tags: mysql, math

Say I have three cards ("first", "second", "third") inside of my database in positions 1 ("foo"), 2 ("bar"), and 3 ("fubar"). I then wanted to move fubar to the front. Then they would be be in order 1 ("fubar"), 2 ("foo"), 3 ("bar").

Now each of the cards belongs to a list, and every card for every list is inside this database. Meaning that only the cards the belong to the same list need their positions updated.

What would be the best way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a unique constraint involving the "position", it is very difficult (if not impossible) to do in a single query, but if there is not...

```
UPDATE theTable 
SET position = IF(otherField='fubar'
                  , [new_position]
                  , IF([new_position] < [old_position]
                       , position + 1
                       , position - 1
                      )
                 ) 
WHERE [condition indicating list] 
      AND (
            ([new_position] < [old_position] 
             AND position BETWEEN [new_position] AND [old_position]
            )
           OR 
            ([new_position] > [old_position] 
             AND position BETWEEN [old_position] AND [new_position]
            )
          ) 
;
```

If there is a unique constraint, you can usually get around it by doing two queries; one to send them to an "out of the way" range, and another (adjusted accordingly) to bring them back into their new positions.

Edit: This only works for moving 'fubar' to a lower position; if moving higher, you would need `<=`, and `position - 1`.

Edit2: Oh, hmm, actually this only works from "last to first". You would need to know the original position of 'fubar' to prevent the ones after it from getting moved further back, leaving a gap.

Updated: With known "old_position", we can do moves forward or backward with the same query.

Comment: A unique constraint makes no difference. The principle of swapping things around is always the same. Move 'a' to 'x'. Move 'b' to 'a'. Move 'x' to 'b'.

Comment: Actually it does, at least in the above case, because 'fubar' becomes 1 before 'foo' leaves the position, or vice versa... at least whenever I've had to do such a query. Yeah, you would think it wouldn't check until it's done, but it effectively doesn't in my experience. ....or I am just misremembering...I am getting older. ;)

Comment: If that was the case - I mean, if you do it that way - then you no longer know which 'foo' is which.

Comment: @Strawberry There is only one foo, only the positions are being changed and momentarily colliding. This is of course assuming `position` is indeed a field, and the asker is not trying to actually affect internal row order.